# Data in my HTML forms vanishes when the web refreshes

Tags: php, html, mysql, chat

I've tried to make an small chat only with PHP, HTML and MySQL. The main problem with it is that when you're writing and the web refreshes, the text you're writing disappears. How can I solve it? Here is the code:

Chat (MySQL connection details have been removed):

```
<?php
$_POST['text'] = '';
session_start();
include 'status.php';
$_SESSION['status'] = status($_SESSION['nick']);
if(IsSet($_SESSION['nick']) && IsSet($_SESSION['pass'])){
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.ico">

<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "15";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
$_SESSION['text'] = $_POST['text'];
$con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<body>
    <h4>Chat: </h4>
    <form align="center" name="form" method="POST" action="/chat/speak.php">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['nick'] . ': '; ?>
    <input name='text' type='text' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['text']; ?>" style="width: 500px;"><br>
     Person: <select id="so" name="private">
      <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY nick");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $nick = $row['nick'];
        echo "<option value='$nick' selected='selected'>$nick</option>";
        }
      ?>
    <option value="public" selected="selected"> PUBLIC </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Speak!"></form>
</body>
<?php
echo '<hr/>';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY time DESC");

echo "<div align='left' name='chat'>
<h2 align='center'><u>Conversation: </u></h2>";
echo '<hr/>';
echo "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$author = $row['author'];
$message = $row['message'];
$color = $row['color'];
$p = $row['p'];
$destinatary = $row['PRIVATE'];

if($p == 1){
    if($author == $_SESSION['nick'] || $destinatary == $_SESSION['nick']){
    echo "<li align='left'>" . "<b><font color='$color'>Private from: $author</font></b>" . "<b><font color='$color'> - </font></b>" . "<font color='$color'>$message</font><hr>";}
}else{
    echo "<li align='left'>" . "<b><font color='$color'>$author</font></b>" . "<b><font color='$color'> - </font></b>" . "<font color='$color'>$message</font><hr>";
}}
mysqli_close($con);
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
}else{
    echo 'You are not logged!';
}
?>
```

Where the main form goes (MySQL connection details have been removed):

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli('', '', '', '');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if(IsSet($_POST['text']) && ($_POST['text']) != ''){
if($_POST['private'] == 'public'){

$nick = $_SESSION['nick'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$time = date('c');
$color = $_SESSION['color'];

$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text);

$sql = "INSERT INTO chat (author, message, time, color, p, PRIVATE)
VALUES ('$nick', '$text', '$time', '$color', '0', '')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: /chat/chat.php');
} else {
    echo "Error";
}

$conn->close();
}else{
        $nick = $_SESSION['nick'];
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        $time = date('c');
        $color = $_SESSION['color'];
        $destinatary = $_POST['private'];

        $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$text);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO chat (author, message, time, color, p, PRIVATE)
        VALUES ('$nick', '$text', '$time', '$color', '1', '$destinatary')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            header('Location: /chat/chat.php');
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }

        $conn->close();
}}else{
    header('Location: /chat/chat.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: You should look into using Prepared Statements instead of injecting the variables into the query manually like that.

Comment: You should use Ajax to load new content without refreshing the whole page (which is done using JavaScript, not JAVA). How is the page refreshing? Meta refresh every x seconds? In that case, you either need to remove that and let the users refresh the page manually or you do need some JavaScript.

Comment: you can refresh a part of the chat without the form with JS. work with ID's in that case

Comment: How can I refresh just one part?